# Problem uploading APK to Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-security

I created the game through Appsgeyser. I have a problem in the APK file, Google Play Console writes me that my application contains one or more libraries with known security problems what should I do ?

Comment: Generate signed apk through android studio itself

Comment: they provided a list of libraries with the issues right ? Please add affected libraries in the question.